# Make command would modify the code indent and line feed of cpp file when I am using vscode to edit the cpp file on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, visual-studio-code

I use make command to compile my c++ project and edit my source files with vscode on Ubuntu. But when I run the make command in the terminal, my c++ files will be modified. The original code indent of my c++ file is 4 whitespace but after compile, the code indent will be modified as 2. And the long line will be split into several short lines. Does someone know why this happens and how to prevent the compile process from modifying the source code?

Comment: It might not be a case of actually changing your code file content. Instead the representation of tabulators might differe. Can you double check that the code file is actually changed? Also please check and report, whether you have indented with tabulators or with blanks.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds unlikely, inasmuch as you are attributing it to `make`.  Although it is possible that your makefile contains rules that run some kind of code formatter on the source files, that is by no means common.  And in that case, it would be a characteristic of the makefile or maybe of your IDE, not of `make`.